# SQL syntax checker in phpMyAdmin rejects good code?

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I'm using the SQL window in phpMyAdmin (3.5.7) to insert rows into a MySql table, but am having problems with the syntax checker. It's running on Windows Server 2003.

If I click the "INSERT" button to generate a template, then overtype the values in the template, there is no problem. However I because I need to populate a large number of rows I have auto-generated INSERT statements using Excel, pasted them into a text editor, and then pasted them into the same phpMyAdmin SQL window. The results are baffling...

The statement below (generated using Excel/text editor/copy&paste) gives an error:

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near ''timeslot' ('slot_no', 'slot_starttime') VALUES (3,'00:30')' at
>   line 1

```
INSERT INTO 'timeslot' ('slot_no', 'slot_starttime') VALUES (2,'00:15')
```

The statement below is fine however (it was constructed by clicking the INSERT button on the SQL window then over-typing the text in the template:

```
INSERT INTO `timeslot`(`slot_no`, `slot_starttime`) VALUES (2,'00:15')
```

I have copied and pasted both statements into this post directly from the phpMyAdmin window. They look pretty much the same to me, so I can't understand why the first one fails.

???

Comment: The first one has quotes around the column names (so they are not treated as column names). If you want something around them then use back ticks (personally I avoid them - I would rather it complained at me as early as possible if I used a silly column name).

Answer (score 3):

If you have pasted the results directly as you say, there is a syntax error.

In MYSQL you cannot enclose field or table names using the apostrophe sign. Rather you've got to use the BACK-QUOTE (on the tilde key)

So the following is WRONG:

```
INSERT INTO 'timeslot' ('slot_no', 'slot_starttime') VALUES (2,'00:15')
```

And the folowing is CORRECT:

```
INSERT INTO `timeslot` (`slot_no`, `slot_starttime`) VALUES (2,'00:15')
```

And even the following is CORRECT (without the back-quotes):

```
INSERT INTO timeslot (slot_no, slot_starttime) VALUES (2,'00:15')
```

The common single quote (') is used only for VALUES in an SQL statement.

Comment: Or to be more precise: the common single quote (') is used only for string (character) literals.